# Parsing a csv file to add details to xml file

Tags: python, xml, csv, scripting

Ned help to parse a csv file which has following details to xml file

csv file is in the following format:

```
name,ip,timeout
domain\user1,10.119.77.218,9000
domain\user2,2.80.189.26,9001
domain\user3,4.155.10.110,9002
domain\user4,9.214.119.86,9003
domain\user5,4.178.187.27,9004
domain\user6,3.76.178.117,9005
```

The above details from csv needs to be added to XML file which has the following format:

```
<login>
      <entry name="domain\user1" ip="10.119.77.218" timeout="9000"/>
      <entry name="domain\user2" ip="2.80.189.26" timeout="9001"/>
      <entry name="domain\user11" ip="4.155.10.110" timeout="12000"/>
      ...
</login>
```

Need some script because there are tones of files which needs to be converted. I tried the following tool:
https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-xml.htm

But the above tool converts individual row to separate entry which is not needed. Looking for your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please show what you wrote and explain the specific problem you need help with.

Comment: This is about a dozen lines of code with [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).  Please try to do your own work first and [edit] your question with a coding attempt if you have a specific problem.

Comment: If you use the Convert CSV to XML Properties button that tool does what you want.

Comment: I tried that convertcsv.com link, and it worked! You just need to click the 'Convert CSV to XML Properties' button, emphasis on **Properties**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of CSV/XML file is simple you can use `csv` module and construct the string directly (for more complicated scenarios I recommend `lxml`/`bs4` modules):

```py
import csv

with open("your_data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    data = list(reader)

out = ["<login>"]
for line in data:
    s = " ".join(f'{k}="{v}"' for k, v in zip(header, line))
    out.append(f"\t<entry {s} />")
out.append("</login>")

print(*out, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```xml
<login>
        <entry name="domain\user1" ip="10.119.77.218" timeout="9000" />
        <entry name="domain\user2" ip="2.80.189.26" timeout="9001" />
        <entry name="domain\user3" ip="4.155.10.110" timeout="9002" />
        <entry name="domain\user4" ip="9.214.119.86" timeout="9003" />
        <entry name="domain\user5" ip="4.178.187.27" timeout="9004" />
        <entry name="domain\user6" ip="3.76.178.117" timeout="9005" />
</login>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have data that should be XML-escaped, here's a simple starter for using the standard xml.etree module:

```py
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("login")
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        ET.SubElement(root, "entry", row)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

`ET.SubElement(root, "entry", row)` does most of the real work, along with Python's DictReader: each row dict becomes the attributes on an entry node:

```xml
<login>
  <entry name="domain\user1" ip="10.119.77.218" timeout="9000" />
  <entry name="domain\user2" ip="2.80.189.26" timeout="9001" />
  <entry name="domain\user3" ip="4.155.10.110" timeout="9002" />
  <entry name="domain\user4" ip="9.214.119.86" timeout="9003" />
  <entry name="domain\user5" ip="4.178.187.27" timeout="9004" />
  <entry name="domain\user6" ip="3.76.178.117" timeout="9005" />
</login>
```

Comment: FYI: `{k: v for k, v in row.items()}` can be just `row`

Comment: @MarkTolonen, oh my gosh, thanks! I had it in my mind that I needed an explicit dict structure because a previous version didn't use DictReader... guess I had curly braces stuck in my mind. Thanks again.